# Reusable chat Application on Android

Tags: android, chat

Is there a reusable chat library for android which i can reuse/customize and reuse as a part of my own application?

Comment: Wikipedia has a good list of Android OpenSource Apps, may be this is helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_Android_applications

Answer (score 0):

You can do XMPP with [smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)